# How to add the attribute of title in chart.render() method of canvas js dynamically with the help of select elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvasjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var dps = []; //dataPoints. 

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
                text: "Accepting DataPoints from User Input"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dps
            }]
        });

        function addDataPointsAndRender() {
            xValue = Number(document.getElementById("xValue").value);
            yValue = Number(document.getElementById("yValue").value);
            dps.push({
                x: xValue,
                y: yValue
            });
            chart.render();
        }

        var renderButton = document.getElementById("renderButton");
        renderButton.addEventListener("click", addDataPointsAndRender);
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
X Value:
<input id="xValue" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter X-Value"> Y Value:
<input id="yValue" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Y-Value">


<select id="select1">
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="pie">Pie</option>
    <option value="column">Column</option>
</select>
</p>


<button id="renderButton">Add DataPoint & Render</button>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 270px; width: 100%;">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above code how I can change the value of chart type in data attribute of this function
data: [{
type: "line",
dataPoints: dps
}]
dynamically with the help of html select
options?? plz help me as I am beginner in JS and solutions with the help of jquery will also be welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically update chart type by setting `chart.options.data[0].type = "newValue";` & re-rendering the chart by calling `chart.render();`. Check out [CanvasJS documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/) for more info. Below is the working code.

```js
var dps = []; //dataPoints

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Accepting DataPoints from User Input"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: dps
  }]
});

function addDataPointsAndRender() {
  var xValue = Number(document.getElementById("xValue").value);
  var yValue = Number(document.getElementById("yValue").value);
  chart.options.data[0].type = document.getElementById("select1").value;

  dps.push({
    x: xValue,
    y: yValue
  });
  chart.render();
}

var renderButton = document.getElementById("renderButton");
renderButton.addEventListener("click", addDataPointsAndRender);
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
X Value:
<input id="xValue" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter X-Value"> Y Value:
<input id="yValue" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Y-Value">
<select id="select1">
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="pie">Pie</option>
  <option value="column">Column</option>
</select>

<button id="renderButton">Add DataPoint &amp; Render</button>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 270px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

You can even change the chart type just by changing the dropdown by binding change event. Below is the updated code.

```js
var dps = []; //dataPoints

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Accepting DataPoints from User Input"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: dps
  }]
});

function addDataPointsAndRender() {
  var xValue = Number(document.getElementById("xValue").value);
  var yValue = Number(document.getElementById("yValue").value);

  dps.push({
    x: xValue,
    y: yValue
  });
  chart.render();
}
document.getElementById("select1").addEventListener("change", function(e){
    chart.options.data[0].type = this.value;
  chart.render();
});

var renderButton = document.getElementById("renderButton");
renderButton.addEventListener("click", addDataPointsAndRender);
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
X Value:
<input id="xValue" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter X-Value"> Y Value:
<input id="yValue" type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter Y-Value">

<button id="renderButton">Add DataPoint &amp; Render</button>

<br/>Change Chart Type:
<select id="select1">
  <option value="line">Line</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="pie">Pie</option>
  <option value="column">Column</option>
</select>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 270px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```